# Referencing to each element in a dictionary of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, tuples

By using the following code, I have been able to transform my dataframe `df` (shown in attached **Picture1**) into dictionary of subset dataframes (split on basis of rows sharing same Year, Month, Week).
Resultant dictionary is shown in **Picture2**.

```
dict_df = dict(tuple(df.groupby(['Year', 'Month', 'Week'])))
print(dict_df)
```

Next, I am trying to reference elements in `Open` column in `dict_df` by using the following code and the output is in **Photo3**:

```
for item in dict_df.keys():
    print(dict_df[item]['Open'])
    print(type(dict_df[item]['Open']))
```

**Question:**

How do I reference to any item (say, 0th or 1st or any ) within the `Open` column in **Picture3**? I tried `print(dict_df[item]['Open'][0])` but I get error `get_loc raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: 0`

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Use `iloc` like `print(dict_df[item]['Open'].iloc[0])`

Comment: @jezrael `.iloc[0]` works. How do I change the datatype of such reference item to float (its string presently)? I tried `dict_df[item]['Open'].iloc[0].astype(float)` but get error. Any other way to smartly convert into float?